# Faster way to print an array cell than doing a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

So I have an array like:

```
var arra= new String [50,50];
// I add in arrays and for every added row, update count by 1. The columns are till incount which is less than 50.

for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<incount;j++)
  {
    print (bigsub[i,j]);
  }
}
```

Is there a faster way I can do this? Can I do this for the inner array as well?

Comment: To print an array in javascript, you could use this `alert(arrayObj.join('\n'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print an array in javascript, you could use this

```
alert(arrayObj.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify(array)`, I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is print it (for debugging purposes) you can use @vimalnath's suggestion in the question comment above.
If however you want to do this for some heavy duty operations and you are open to using HTML 5 then you could employ multiple Web Workers to do this job asynchronously for you.